# нужно сделать Арифметическую прогрессию в Java

Tags: java

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int D  = scan.nextInt();
int [] S =new int [D];
int n = scan.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    S[n] = scan.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
    if(S[n]-S[n-1]==D) {
        System.out.println(D);
    } else {
        System.out.println(0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: error 14 строке  показывает в первом for

Comment: А из чего Вы прогрессию делаете?

Answer (score 1):

Вы в цикле обращаетесь к элементу `S` по индексу `n`, но цикл у вас по `i`, надо `S[i]`, а не `S[n]`
Во втором цикле аналогично.

Но и сам цикл у вас до `n`, а размер массива у вас `D`, наверное цикл нужно тоже до `D` делать...